# Limit what methods are allowed for a route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm trying to remove the `PUT` method on one of my controllers, but I cannot find a way to do so without going through and mapping each method to a function.

I have the following in my route file:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function() {
    $defaultOptions = ['except' => ['create', 'edit']];

    Route::resource('recipies', 'RecipieController', $defaultOptions);
    //This is the one that I am trying to restrict
    Route::resource('recipies.ingredients', 'Recipie\IngredientController', ['except' => ['create', 'edit', 'show']]); 

    Route::resource('ingredients', 'IngredientController', $defaultOptions);
});
```

I know that I can do the following to accomplish what I am wanting, but I am hoping that there is some option where I can limit what methods are allowed

```
Route::get('recipies/{recipie_id}/ingredients', 'Recipie\IngredientController');
Route::patch('recipies/{recipie_id}/ingredients/{ingredient_id}', 'Recipie\IngredientController');
Route::delete('recipies/{recipie_id}/ingredients/{ingredient_id}', 'Recipie\IngredientController');
```

While the above will work, I feel that it is messy and am hoping for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

**PUT** method is mapped to **update** method of a resource controller. Add this method to the list of excluded methods:

```
Route::resource('recipies.ingredients', 'Recipie\IngredientController', ['except' => ['create', 'edit', 'show', 'update]]);
```

Comment: The problem with that is it then also removes the `PATCH` request method, which I want to keep. I want the api to be able to update (`PATCH`) a resource, not replace (`PUT`) the entire thing.

Comment: Unfortunately, Laravel's resource controller treat the two methods as the same. It's up to you if your implementation writes/replaces the resource or just "patches" it. If you want to disallow PUT you can either add a middleware for that route that would throw MethodNotAllowedException exception on PUT or just handle that in the controller itself, whatever works for you.